# Read an InstantDB .db file

Tags: database, export

I have our database files that we've recovered from our server that was running ShopSite 7.  ShopSite themselves are no help.  Anyhow, I've managed to recover our orders and customers tables.

However, they are a .db file.  Its not paradox according to

```
pxinfo -f path_to_db
```

The begining of the file starts like this (copied from vim)

```
IDB 2.1^@>^@^@^@^@^H^@^@^^G^@^@àç^Z^@ÐD6^@@^@^@^@^C^@^@^@ø<^@^@^H^A^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^O^@^@^@Date_i18n_N65
```

Searching on IDB 2.1 lead me to InstantDB, which has been MIA since 2001 apparently.  I've tired [DbVizualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/) but had no luck with that.

Anyone have any ideas how to read this file?  See the [pastie link](http://pastie.org/626312) for the header row and first record.  It looks like garbage, but there is a pattern there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this file:

http://jmatrix.net/actions/attachment.do?id=7F000001-81B1FB-12063F02CCB-1BF3

it's the InstantDB java driver, then get DataBrowser from jmatrix.net

Start DataBrowser like so: java -jar databrowser.jar

Go Edit -> Edit Preferences -> Driver Manager -> Add, and add the idb-2.jar driver you downloaded above.

Then, go Database -> New Connection -> Instant DB, and browser to wherever your .db file is.

Let me know if this works, I don't have an example file to try out.

Comment: Thank you!!!! That connected me to the DB, now I just have to figure how to dump the data to a csv file and I'm done.  Thank you!!!!

Comment: Looking more @ DataaBrowser its only showing sys tbls and no data.   Any Ideas?

Comment: try "SELECT * from table-name"? and click the magnifying glass icon (execute SQL as query)

Comment: turns out the DB I was using is an instantDB but in a proprietary format.  Down with ShopSite!